# calculating the size of a node in a doubly linkedlist

Tags: c, struct

I have created a node in C using the struct:

```
struct node{
       int data;
       struct node* left;
       struct node* right;
}
```

Now i am calculating the size of the node using the following code

```
printf("%d", size of(struct node));
```

The output is 6, I am using the Turbo c++ compiler.

Kindly clear me why the size of node is 6?

Comment: Why using Turbo c++ compiler to compile a C code?

Comment: You may invoke *undefined behavior* for passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. You should use `%zu` to print `size_t`. Then, try getting size of each members in the structure.

Comment: Are you sure you are using two tokens `size of` instead of `sizeof` operator?

Comment: i mean to say that if we have declare a struct which has one int variable, one float and one char then the size will be 7, but when it  pointer varibales to itself the what will be the size?

Comment: Could be 7 in case you define your aligment to 1 (gcc `#pragma pack(1)`). BTW I think the problem is well explained in the proposed duplicate question. Probably you are using small memory model where `int` and pointers are16 bits.

Comment: don't use Turbo C++ anymore. It's not a C nor C++ compiler because it was released long before the first C++ standard. And C++ is not extended C, it's a different language so don't use C++ compiler for C code

Comment: Maybe you should be starting with simpler things on your platform like *sizeof(int)* and *sizeof(int**) - Those answers will get you going towards more questions. If you want an explanation on the figures returned from there, read up *near* and *far* pointers in the Turbo-C docs and you will have a nice example on why you should never be *assuming* sizeof()s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look into `struct node`, run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

int main(void){
    printf("sizeof (struct node) is %zu\n", sizeof (struct node));
    printf("offsetof(struct node, data) is %zu\n", offsetof(struct node, data));
    printf("sizeof data is %zu\n", sizeof (struct node){}.data);
    printf("offsetof(struct node, left) is %zu\n", offsetof(struct node, left));
    printf("sizeof left is %zu\n", sizeof (struct node){}.left);
    printf("offsetof(struct node, right) is %zu\n", offsetof(struct node, right));
    printf("sizeof right is %zu\n", sizeof (struct node){}.right);
    return 0;
}
```

There might be some padding bits/bytes in a struct, making `sizeof (struct node)` greater than `sizeof (struct node){}.data) + sizeof (struct node){}.left) + sizeof (struct node){}.right)`.

Also note that to print a `size_t`, you should use `"%zu"`( or `"%Iu"` if using MSVC), rather than `%d`.

Comment: The OP question refer to the fact that the result is 6 instead of an usual 12.

Comment: Very clear answer - on how to get size of structure elements - take a punt at why the size is 6, and this will get my upvote.

Comment: @LPs Yes, of course. I suppose if he run this code on his implementation, he'll be able be to learn why `sizeof (struct node)` is 6 by checking all its components.

Comment: @mksteve But there a little problem: `sizeof (struct node)` is 24 on my machine, so I can't tell what's going on on OP's machine...

Comment: @mksteve Anyway, the output is implementation-defined

Answer (score 6):

"Classic" Turbo C++ targets 16 bit DOS (later versions support 16 bit Windows), so near pointers and `int` are 2 bytes each; being them all the same, no padding is required for alignment, and the total size amounts to the plain sum of its elements (2+2+2=6 bytes).

The fact that such pointers point to other `node` structures doesn't affect their size (why should it?).

Answer (score 1):

Both "int" and "pointer" are related with the platform. In different platform, you will get different results. You can have a try.